# Deploying BizTalk remotely using powershell provider

Tags: powershell, biztalk, biztalk-2010, powershell-remoting

I'm trying to write PowerShell scripts for deploying BizTalk applications remotely. we have BizTalk group setup to deploy applications. currently when I try to deploy an application I'm getting an error while initializing the PS-drive. it is trying to Login as the Anonymous user for some reason. Can anyone please help me in resolving this?

I'm attaching the commands I use to remote and initializing the drive below.

```
Invoke-Command -EnableNetworkAccess -ConfigurationName 'Microsoft.PowerShell32' -ComputerName $server.Name -ScriptBlock $webAppScript -ArgumentList $application, $server, $environmentConfig,$global:tempLocation
```

Initialize the drive is part of the script block that runs remotely.

```
    if($env:Processor_Architecture -eq "x86")
        {        
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Running PowerShell x86"

            Function BizTalk: { Set-Location BizTalk: }
            Function BizTalk: { Set-Location BizTalk:\ }

            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Loading PowerShell provider for BizTalk snap-in"

            $InitializeDefaultBTSDrive = $false
            Add-PSSnapin -Name BizTalkFactory.PowerShell.Extensions    

            New-PSDrive -Scope Global -Name BizTalk -Root BizTalk:\ -PsProvider BizTalk -Instance $server.DBInstance -Database $server.DBName
}
```

Error that I'm getting.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We have used very well tested solution to deploy BizTalk apps using PowerShell. Please see the detailed steps here [deployment using PowerShell](https://vikas15bhardwaj.wordpress.com/2015/02/06/biztalk-application-deployment-using-btdf-and-powershell/)

Comment: The blog post is helpful, but if you could post some of the content here it'd be a better answer.  Nothing's more frustrating than seeing an old post with a broken link to a blog, right?

Comment: Well, I could have added the answer here but wanted to avoid copy paste. the blog has very detailed steps listed, Its not short answer, so thought of providing the link, however, I understand in future if link goes away the answer will be invalid. So I will edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

There is sometimes an issue with BizTalk known as the "Double Hop Issue".  This can happen when SQL isn't on the same server as BizTalk (which is the way it typically is in a production environment).

I've got it before when running WMI on various machines; and I never got a real fix for it.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c8ca93cc-dd7c-4c17-8e9d-9ba814c9cb12/login-failed-for-user-nt-authorityanonymous-logon?forum=biztalkesb

Comment: Late to the party, `Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Client -DelegateComputer * -Force` should fix allowing delegation of the credentials.  Since you're remoting onto a BizTalk server, then jumping onto a SQL server.